# delphi как переназначить название процедуры интерфейса в объекте если она overload

Tags: delphi

как переназначить название процедуры интерфейса в объекте если она overload

```
  IIntr = interface
   procedure Other;
   procedure Same(); overload;
   procedure Same(i:integer); overload;
  end;
  TIntr  =  class (TInterfacedObject,IIntr)

      procedure IIntr.Other = myOther;
      procedure IIntr.Same = mySame1;
      procedure IIntr.Same = mySame2; << [dcc32 Error]  E2004 Identifier redeclared: 'Same'
      procedure myOther;
      procedure mySame1;
      procedure mySame2(i:integer);
  end;

implementation

{ TIntr }

procedure TIntr.myOther;
begin

end;

procedure TIntr.mySame1;
begin

end;

procedure TIntr.mySame2(i:integer);
begin

end;
```

Comment: А вам обязательно нужно, чтоб метод интерфейса и метод вашего класса отличались по названию? Проще же не указывать соответствия вручную, а объявить метод с тем же именем и списком параметров, что и в классе, и тогда они автоматически будут сопоставлены.

Comment: На англоязычном SO пишут что для перегруженных методов это невозможно https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40224018/how-to-create-resolution-clauses-for-overloaded-interface-methods

Comment: @Герман Борисов
  спасибо в больших объектах хотелось бы иметь другое название проц что бы не путатся какая проц от какого интерфейса а у меня такая штука что такое название метода в объекте уже есть и эта проц совершенно другое делает я конечно скомпилил прогу и все норм работает но ток в логе компилятора одна надпись осталась [dcc32 Warning] : W1010 Method 'Add' hides virtual method of base type 'TClass'